# NSManagedObject without values

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Im passing a `NSManagedObject` to a UIView. So Im showing a `UITableView` of meetings brought from CoreData, if you tap on one of the meetings you will be able to see, on another view, more info of that meeting, info that is contained in a `NSManagedObject`. I want to pass that `NSManagedObject` to the view that will show its info.
So I created a init method of that view like this:

```
-(id)initWithMeeting:(NSManagedObject *)aMeeting{

    _theMeeting = aMeeting;

    return self;
}
```

Then I use the info in the `_theMeeting` object to show it in the view that I just created in the `ViewDidLoad`. The problem is that whenever I try to access any of the values of the NSManagedObject it crashes, it has values in the `init` but not in the `ViewDidLoad`.
I believe it has something to do with the `Managed Oriented Context`, but the `Managed Oriented Context` never disspears, is an attribute of the `AppDelegate`.
So I dont know how to pass that Object and keep it.

I also declared theMeeting:

```
 @property(nonatomic, copy)NSManagedObject *theMeeting;
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the accessor to assign theMeeting? I think you're just bypassing it so aMeeting is not retained or copied, and therefore the crash.

Comment: you where right but now after changing it to 'self.theMeeting' I get [NSManagedObject copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to ....

Comment: NSManagedObject doesn't confirm to the NSCopying protocol. If you just want to display the data, change "copy" to "retain"